# File sync issue from one org to another org

Tags: apex, files, heapsizelimit

We are having a kind of Connector Application (bidirectional) which sync data between the two salesforce org which are using two different platform apps.

This connector application has a functionality where it syncs the files uploaded on one salesforce org with another salesforce org through APIs calls in Apex Job scheduler.

Currently, we do have a limitation for file size of 7.5 MB synced, but **we have the requirement to increase this document size limitation to 10 to 12 MB file size synced between two Salesforce org**.

We have created an object that will hold the file-related data such as Title, file Extention, parentId along with the Body(this Body is the Base64Encoded BLOB data). The batch class will do the API call and has the object mentioned above as a parameter.

We tried to upload the file with a size greater than 7.5 MB and observed that the system crossed the heap size limits and returned the error (This is a typical salesforce Apex limitation).

**We want to bypass this situation and want to sync the 10-12 MB uploaded file transfer from one org to another.
We are looking for a better approach to resolve this problem.**

Comment: Break up the blob and reassemble it on the other side. This can be as simple as splitting the encoded blob into whatever size chunks, tagging the chunk as "chunk #1...N" in your send and have the receiver collect and reassemble.

Comment: @identigral, we tried this approach, but in our use-case when we read the entire blob data using SOQL in apex (job schedule class) and tried to serialize it to create the chunks, we again ran into a Heap Size issue.
Note:- our use case is related to the server to server execution, and there are no client components are involved like javascript.

Comment: If you read the entire blob and it exceeds the limits, you'll run out of heap. You'll need to break up the file when you upload it or in another batch job post-upload.

Comment: @identigral Uploading of a file is handled by another app-exchange product (3rd party), We can't do much about it.
We came into the picture post the upload file trigger execution.
Could you brief about how one can chunk the blob data into another batch job class?

Comment: Run a post-upload job that grabs the file and chunks it up, then stores chunks somewhere (custom object).

Comment: When the post upload job runs, and it reads 10MB size blob data to create the chunks out of it, we have to use serialisation to convert the blob data into a string but this serialisation of blob data make the size of data 13MB which exceeds apex heap size limits before you start creating the chunks.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to avoid reading it into memory. If you can't do that, you're out of luck.